# Узнать, что ранее каталог не был создан

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, totalcommander

Total Commander последней версии умеет делать следующее:

Если зайти куда-нибудь вглубь, а потом постепенно, а потом вернуться на несколько папок назад, то он выделит те папки, которых ранее не было.

Собственно вопрос, а как он это может делать?

У меня есть идеи:

1. Он делает слепок дерева файловой системы на один момент, а потом делает сравнение с новым слепком и так он находит новые директории.
2. Есть какая-то WinAPI функция

Comment: Можно определить время создания каталога. И сравнить со временем просмотра каталога.

Answer (score 2):

Можно определить время создания каталога. И сравнить со временем просмотра каталога.

```
try
            {
                //Твой каталог
                DateTime dt = Directory.GetCreationTime(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

                //DateTime время просмотра каталога
                //Для примера получим текущую дату
                var dt2 = DateTime.Now;
                var dt2Seconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt2).TotalSeconds ;

                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds > dt2Seconds)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл был создан ранее");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл был создан позднее");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds);
                Console.WriteLine(dt2Seconds);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```